# ifelse with column selection and condition

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

This is my first question here. I am doing my best to keep it reproduceable.
I can´t find any question which solve this issue.

Sample Data

```
library(dplyr)

Data <- data.frame(
    a = sample(1:10),
    b = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    c = sample(1:10),
    x_a = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    x_b = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    y_a = sample(1:10),
    y_b = sample(1:10)
  )
```

Data Print

```
    a b  c x_a x_b y_a y_b
1   3 T  3   F   T  10   8
2   5 F  7   T   F   8   9
3   2 T  9   F   T   6   4
4   8 F  5   T   F   4   7
5   6 F  6   T   F   5   1
6   9 F  2   T   F   1  10
7   4 F  8   T   F   7   5
8   7 F  1   T   T   2   2
9  10 F 10   T   F   3   3
10  1 F  4   F   T   9   6
```

Here is what I want to do. I want to create a new column combinded from the following logic.

```
Data %>% mutate(new = ifelse(starts_with("x") & . == T,rowMeans(starts_with("y")),a))
```

In words: Take cols with a pattern in its names(starts_with("x"). 
If one (minimum) value in each observation is True, take the rowmean from cols named with another pattern (starts_with("y")).
Else (if only False values are in each row), take the value from col a.

Tried multiple approaches with zero success.i spent the whole morning with solving the problem... 
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need `map2_df(Data[grep("x", names(Data))], Data[grep("y", names(Data))], ~ .y  * NA^!as.logical(.x)) %>% rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: or may be `rowMeans(mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(as.logical(x), y, Data$a) , Data[grep("x", names(Data))], Data[grep("y", names(Data))]))`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to set the seed to 1 so that the data can be replicated.

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  a = sample(1:10),
  b = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  c = sample(1:10),
  x_a = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  x_b = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  y_a = sample(1:10),
  y_b = sample(1:10)
)
```

The Data looks as follows:

```
> Data
    a b  c x_a x_b y_a y_b
1   3 T 10   T   F   5  10
2   4 T  2   F   F   8   3
3   5 F  6   T   F   4   4
4   7 T  1   T   F   2   9
5   2 F  9   F   F   1   8
6   8 T  8   F   F   6   2
7   9 F  7   F   T   7   5
8   6 F  5   T   T   9   7
9  10 T  3   F   F   3   1
10  1 F  4   T   F  10   6
```

I decided to convert "T" or "F" to boolean TRUE or FALSE with the type.convert command.

```
Data<-type.convert(Data)
```

You can now use Grep to select columns with "x" on it.  Apply rowSums.  You just want one of the columns to be TRUE.  Therefore, as long as the sum is greater than zero,  you want to take the mean of columns starting with y:

```
Data$new<-ifelse(rowSums(Data[,grep("x",colnames(Data))])>0,rowMeans(Data[,grep("y",colnames(Data))]),Data$a)
```

```
> Data
    a     b  c   x_a   x_b y_a y_b  new
1   3  TRUE 10  TRUE FALSE   5  10  7.5
2   4  TRUE  2 FALSE FALSE   8   3  4.0
3   5 FALSE  6  TRUE FALSE   4   4  4.0
4   7  TRUE  1  TRUE FALSE   2   9  5.5
5   2 FALSE  9 FALSE FALSE   1   8  2.0
6   8  TRUE  8 FALSE FALSE   6   2  8.0
7   9 FALSE  7 FALSE  TRUE   7   5  6.0
8   6 FALSE  5  TRUE  TRUE   9   7  8.0
9  10  TRUE  3 FALSE FALSE   3   1 10.0
10  1 FALSE  4  TRUE FALSE  10   6  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

rowMeans will not directly work with "Starts_with" as it will need a range of columns to calculate mean. The following will work for your above case :

```
 Data <- Data %>% mutate(new = ifelse(x_a == 'T' | x_b == 'T',rowMeans(dplyr::select(.,starts_with("y"))),a))
```

You can directly use 'select' instead of 'dplyr::select' as there is some version issue in my case !